# Create Databricks token for another user

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

After deploying Databricks workspace I would like to add an application user and generate a token for it. Is there a way to have something like:

```
resource "databricks_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id = "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef"
}

resource "databricks_token" "token" {
  service_principal_id = databricks_service_principal.app.application_id
  comment              = "A token"
}
```

Currently [databricks_token](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/token) doesn't support `service_principal_id` field, it only creates token for current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the cloud:

- On AWS there is support for so-called "on behalf of" (OBO) token - there is a dedicated resource for it: `databricks_obo_token` ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/obo_token)).
- On Azure, you can create a separate provider instance to authenticate to Databricks using Service Principal authentication ([doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs#authenticating-with-azure-service-principal)) and generate token using that provider instance (although, frankly speaking, it's better always use AAD auth for service principals on Azure).  Something like this:

```
# this will use "normal" provider instance 
resource "databricks_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id = "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef"
}

# Provider instance for Service Principal
provider "databricks" {
  host                        = azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.workspace_url
  azure_workspace_resource_id = azurerm_databricks_workspace.this.id
  azure_client_id             = var.client_id
  azure_client_secret         = var.client_secret
  azure_tenant_id             = var.tenant_id
  alias = "spn"
}

resource "databricks_token" "token" {
  provider   = databricks.spn
  comment    = "A token"
  depends_on = [databricks_service_principal.app]
}
```

Comment: how to get application_id for resource databricks_service_principal?

Comment: As usual via .id